# How can I combine Columns in DataTable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have  `DataTable` like this:

[image]

I need to combine "Headline 1-2-3" Columns to one, like this:

[image]

Unfortunately `GridView.TableCell` can not be applied here.
How can I combine Columns, using C# ASP.NET?

Comment: `DataTable` is data container, what you are asking for is related to UI, you have to fix that in `GridView`, you can't do that in `DataTable`

Comment: If you want to do it in gridview, use Template column. check http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/52060/merge-3-columns-into-1-column-in-gridview/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asp.net repeater instead of a gridview.

the repeaters DataSource will be your source for the tables and don't forget to DataDind() the repeater.

then in the itemdatabound (rpeaterId.ItemDataBound += {by pressing += visual studio will  suggest to create the method for you by pressing the Tab button twice :) }) function of the repeater you can set a if statement for the headers

You'll need to write more code if you need more help.

I hope this will give you an instight and help you solve your problem.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="region" HeaderText="region" visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="postalcode" HeaderText="postalcode" visible="false"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Address">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
                        <%# Eval("address") + ", " + Eval("city") + ", " + Eval("region") + ", " + Eval("postalcode")%>
                    </asp:Label>                        
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

then all you need to do is return the rquired "bound" data, and let the template do the rest:

```
    private void LoadEmployeeAddress()
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NorthwindDatabase"];
        string sql = "select address, city, region, postalcode from employees;";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```